# S3::putObject(): couldn't connect to host

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a web app made with symfony2, the app is hosted in amazon aws. In the app we are processing some pdf files and we convert them to images and then we upload those images to s3.

The app worked perfect the past 6 months but some days ago we are getting an error in s3.php file when the app start to uploading the images. And the app stop uploading the images to the repo.

```
User Warning: S3::putObject(): [7] couldn't connect to host
```

I made a lot of testing to determine what's happening, in local enviroment the app still working perfect and the code in both sides is the same. I think it could be something related with the aws instance, also I though it was that the date time in server had a delay of 8 minutes, but I also fix that.

Please I need a clue.. Thanks!

Comment: All this issue was because the s3 bucket was located in Brazil and the app instances are in Virginia, so the solution was migrate the s3 bucket to Virginia, that increase the upload speed to the s3 bucket while uploading the images.

Comment: initially thought that this issue might not be applicable to me as both my EC2 and the S3 we're hosted in Ireland, then I remembered that my S3 is hosted on an old bucket in Virginia ... thanks for pointing this out